# How to dynamically construct resource names using AWS SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I'm new to AWS and SAM, so this may be an obvious question, but I just can't find an answer to it. I'm trying to construct a SAM template that allows the user to inject a parameter that will affect the names of all resources within. Specifically, an "environment" parameter can be passed in, which will then be used to qualify all resource names:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31"
Parameters:
  EnvironmentParameter:
    Type: "String"
    Default: "default"
Resources:
  GetTermsAndConditionsFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::Function"
    Properties:
      # TODO: prepend the environment somehow so I get "$ENVIRONMENT_MyFunction" instead
      FunctionName: "MyFunction"
      Handler: "..."
      ...
```

How can I dynamically construct a `FunctionName` using `EnvironmentParameter`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the Cloudformation functions work in SAM templates as well. So you would use the `Fn::Sub` function to replace the EnvironmentParameter in your `FunctionName`

```
FunctionName: !Sub "${EnvironmentParameter}_MyFunction"
```

[Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) for more details on `Fn::Sub` function.

Hope this helps!